# CSS Grid vendor prefixes not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I followed the IE 10+ CSS Grid vendor prefixes specification listed [here](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/11/26/should-i-try-to-use-the-ie-implementation-of-css-grid-layout/) but CSS grid is not properly working in IE 11 for me. Neither does it work in Edge. Everything's fine on Google Chrome and Firefox though. Here's my [codepen](https://codepen.io/eliya33/pen/WEPaZv). I tried changing the vmin and fr units into px but the problem still persists. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? It's my first time playing around with Grid and maybe it's just a simple fix I'm just not seeing. Thanks in advance

```css
/*

  1fr = 167px(width of uppermost leftmost white rectangle of painting)
  1vmin = .01 * 726px(height of entire painting)

*/

/* General Styles */
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  background: #000;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
}

/* Margins */
.margin-right {
  margin-right: 2.6vmin;
}

.margin-bottom {
  margin-bottom: 2.6vmin;
}

/* Colors */
.white {
  background: #fff;
}

.yellow {
  background: #ffcf00;
}

.red {
  background: #df0000;
}

.blue {
  background: #2822dd;
}

.black {
  background: #000;
}

/* Grid Container */
.grid-container {

}

/* Grid One */
.grid-one {
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1.72fr .50fr .38fr .28fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 9.50vmin;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1.72fr .50fr .38fr .28fr;
  grid-template-rows: 9.50vmin;
}

/* Grid Two */
.grid-two {
  -ms-grid-columns: .51fr 2.22fr .50fr .38fr .28fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 29vmin;
  grid-template-columns: .51fr 2.22fr .50fr .38fr .28fr;
  grid-template-rows: 29vmin;
}

/* Grid Three */
.grid-three {
  -ms-grid-columns: .51fr 2.22fr .50fr .38fr .28fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 19vmin;
  grid-template-columns: .51fr 2.22fr .50fr .38fr .28fr;
  grid-template-rows: 19vmin;
}

/* Grid Four */
.grid-four {
  -ms-grid-columns: .51fr 1.11fr 1.11fr .88fr .28fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 10.06vmin;
  grid-template-columns: .51fr 1.11fr 1.11fr .88fr .28fr;
  grid-template-rows: 10.06vmin;
}

/* Grid Five */
.grid-five {
  -ms-grid-columns: .51fr 1.11fr 1.11fr .88fr .28fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 10.06vmin;
  grid-template-columns: .51fr 1.11fr 1.11fr .88fr .28fr;
  grid-template-rows: 10.06vmin;
}

/* Grid Six */
.grid-six {
  -ms-grid-columns: .51fr 1.11fr 1.11fr .88fr .28fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 6.34vmin;
  grid-template-columns: .51fr 1.11fr 1.11fr .88fr .28fr;
  grid-template-rows: 6.34vmin;
}

/* Grid Seven */
.grid-seven {
  -ms-grid-columns: .51fr 1.11fr 1.11fr .88fr .28fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 2.89vmin;
  grid-template-columns: .51fr 1.11fr 1.11fr .88fr .28fr;
  grid-template-rows: 2.89vmin;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Mondrian</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>


<div class="grid grid-one">
  <div class="white margin-right margin-bottom"></div>
  <div class="white margin-right margin-bottom"></div>
  <div class="yellow margin-bottom"></div>
  <div class="yellow margin-right margin-bottom"></div>
  <div class="white"></div>
</div>

<div class="grid grid-two">
  <div class="white margin-right"></div>
  <div class="red margin-right"></div>
  <div class="yellow margin-bottom"></div>
  <div class="yellow margin-right margin-bottom"></div>
  <div class="white"></div>
</div>

<div class="grid grid-three">
  <div class="white margin-right"></div>
  <div class="red margin-right margin-bottom"></div>
  <div class="white margin-right margin-bottom"></div>
  <div class="white margin-right margin-bottom"></div>
  <div class="white"></div>
</div>

<div class="grid grid-four">
  <div class="white margin-right margin-bottom"></div>
  <div class="black margin-right margin-bottom"></div>
  <div class="white margin-right margin-bottom"></div>
  <div class="white margin-right margin-bottom"></div>
  <div class="white margin-bottom"></div>
</div>

<div class="grid grid-five">
  <div class="yellow margin-right"></div>
  <div class="white margin-right margin-bottom"></div>
  <div class="white margin-right margin-bottom"></div>
  <div class="blue margin-right"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>

<div class="grid grid-six">
  <div class="yellow margin-right"></div>
  <div class="white margin-right"></div>
  <div class="black margin-right margin-bottom"></div>
  <div class="blue margin-right margin-bottom"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>

<div class="grid grid-seven">
  <div class="yellow margin-right"></div>
  <div class="white margin-right"></div>
  <div class="white"></div>
  <div class="white margin-right"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid), " Internet Explorer and Edge implement an [older version of the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-grid-layout-20110407/)". Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mr Lister, I learned that the current implementation from IE10 is outdated...which means it's not possible to see grid properly on IE as of now. Just saw a tweet from @jensimmons that CSS Grid is coming to MS Edge on Oct. 17 though.